# Comparision between AppDynamics and Application Insights

Tags: azure-application-insights, apm, appdynamics, azure-monitoring

I am trying to a good comparison between AppDynamics and Application Insights in regard to Azure App Service.

I tried to google around but couldn't find any good comparison, if someone can point me or summarize here.

Answer (score -9, accepted):

Information I got from another website.

Application Insights (AI) is a very simplistic APM tool today. It does do transaction tracing, it has very limited code and runtime diagnostics, and it doesn’t go very deep into analyzing the browser performance. Application Insights is much more like Google Analytics than like a typical APM tool.

- AI does not support mobile apps, AppDynamics does Android and iOS
- AI only supports Java, .NET, and node.js while AppDynamics supports many
  additional languages and technologies.
- AI requires code changes to do additional metric capture from the
  code. AppDynamics has do this on the fly without code change on most
  languages.
- AI doesn’t so transaction distributed tracing, it has a simple data
  collection model similar to what New Relic does. This makes
  troubleshooting much harder in complex apps. If your app is simple
  it’s not required.
- AI lacks transaction scoring and baselining, you must set manual
  thresholds. AppDynamics does this for every metric and every business
  transaction.
- AI doesn’t monitor databases or data stores. AppDynamics does both.
- AI is SaaS only, while AppDynamics can be deployed on premises or
  SaaS.

Comment: I found your information at https://www.quora.com/What-are-the-difference-between-AppDynamics-vs-Application-Insights-for-Azure-WebApps. The source of the information is Jonah Kowall, **VP Market Development and Insights at AppDynamics** and is perhaps not presenting an unbiased opinion. For an Azure App Service, App Insights is cheap, lives in Azure alongside your App Service, and likely a perfect fit. Of course, that's just my opinion, and I ♥ Azure so I'm biased as well =)

Comment: "AI is SaaS only, while AppDynamics can be deployed on premises or SaaS. " is incorrect, or misleading at best. AI can instrument .NET code running on your own infrastructure with some code changes and a library import (NuGet). However, the data must all go to an Azure subscription for viewing there within the portal...I'm not aware of a way around that.  

I thought that was an important distinction for those of us that run hybrid setups.